npm install is giving error - npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
In my React Native with TypeScript project, I wanted to install dependencies.
To install Testing Libraries I've used this command:
npm install @testing-library/react-native @testing-library/jest-native --save-dev
But it's giving me this error:
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: productoverviewapp@1.0.0
npm error Found: react@18.2.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"18.2.0" from the root project
npm error   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @testing-library/react-native@12.7.2
npm error   node_modules/@testing-library/react-native
npm error     dev @testing-library/react-native@"*" from the root project
npm error   1 more (react-native)
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^18.3.1" from react-test-renderer@18.3.1
npm error node_modules/react-test-renderer
npm error   peer react-test-renderer@">=16.8.0" from @testing-library/react-native@12.7.2
npm error   node_modules/@testing-library/react-native
npm error     dev @testing-library/react-native@"*" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps

-- I've also tried --legacy-peer-deps but, then npm install is not working and I'm not sure what's wrong.
===> Output of npm ls react-dom:
productoverviewapp@1.0.0 /Users/App
└── (empty)

===> Output of npm ls react:
productoverviewapp@1.0.0 /Users/****/App
├─┬ @testing-library/jest-native@5.4.3
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ @testing-library/react-native@12.7.2
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-native-fast-image@8.6.3
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-native@0.74.5
│ ├─┬ @react-native/virtualized-lists@0.74.87
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-shallow-renderer@16.15.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
└── react@18.2.0

I've tried --legacy-peer-deps, it's working temporary but when I try to add ESLint, it's again giving me error.
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm error
npm error While resolving: @testing-library/jest-native@5.4.3
npm error Found: react@18.2.0


As per your first error message, react-test-renderer@18.3.1 requires react@"^18.3.1", but you only have react@18.2.0.

This clarification helped me lot. Thank you @Derek

I've found solution to this:
Use Yarn instead of npm:
If npm continues to present dependency tree resolution issues, you can switch to yarn, which often handles peer dependency resolution more gracefully:
Install Yarn:
npm install -g yarn

Install Dependencies with Yarn:
yarn add react@18.2.0 react-test-renderer@18.2.0 @testing-library/react-native jest ts-jest @types/jest --dev

Yarn will automatically resolve conflicts that npm struggles with.
